# Review Triage - Salvagable by user

Tags: discussion

I've seen a couple questions in the review triage like this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645966/check-how-many-months-user-buy-auto-renewal-subscription-objective-c

> My customer need to check if end users subscribe (auto renewal subscription) in 12 months continuously then they are become VIP users permanently. Please tell me how to check how many months the user do subscription by Objective C.

This question is, on it's own, not of very high quality. I have seen ones that are very interesting and would add something to the community, that suffer the same problem though.

. In a case like this, often a comment is placed stating something like:

> what did you done till now? Give an reproducable example!

If the user were to do this, this question would be just fine. However, as it stands, it's not. So, this question does not look okay, does not requre some time and effort of editors, I guess it could be flagged but I wouldn't be sure how to flag it properly. Right now I've just been hitting the skip button, but actually I'd want a "Requires editing by user" button. What's the appropriate course of action for this kind of questions?

Comment: Either "too broad" or "unclear" will fit.

Comment: @DavidPostill This does not allow the user to edit his question though.

Comment: Users can edit closed questions. Edits automatically send them to the reopen queue. That's how "on hold"/closing is intended to work.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg Yes, they can. See the comment from Jeffrey.